# FInd Missing number and MIN and MAX Value and find Dublicate values count WITHOUT using PHP inbuild functions.Checked many but no suitable for me

Tags: php, php-7

I am having below array

```
$inputArray = array(1, 2, 5, 7,2);
```

- Now i want to find MIN and MAX Values.
- Second Thing find missing    values in this array
- Third dublicate number count, How can i acheive    this,pls anyone
  help me here.

> my code

```
$inputArray = array(1, 2, 5, 7,2);
$min = 0;
$max = 0;
foreach($inputArray as $inputValue){
    if ($inputValue >= $min) { 
       $max = $inputValue; // maximum value
    }
}

foreach($inputArray as $inputValue){
    if ($max >= $inputValue) { 
       $min = $inputValue; // minimum value
    }
}
echo $max;
```

**Note: Mainthing we should not use single PHP inbuild functions.**

Comment: Well your max and min tests are the wrong way round

Comment: Can you please help me here @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$inputArray = array(1, 2, 5, 7,2);
$i=0;
foreach($inputArray as $inputValue){
   if($i == 0){
      $min = $inputValue;
      $max = $inputValue;
   }
   if($inputValue > $max){
      $max = $inputValue;
   }
   if($inputValue < $min){
      $min = $inputValue;
   }
   $i +=1;
}
echo $i ."<br>"; // array count

echo $min ."<br>";

echo $max ."<br>";
```

Comment: @RAJA add <br> see again code